# React useEffect: Function Execution Order Issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to achieve something like the following using `useEffect` in React:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    ApiCall_A()
        .then(ApiCall_B)
}, []);
```

However, it seems like `ApiCall_B()` does not wait for `ApiCall_A()` to finish executing. I have tried rewriting the useEffect multiple times but to no success. I suspect there might be something wrong with `ApiCall_A()`.

Here is the code for `ApiCall_A()`:

```js
async function ApiCall_A() {
  const gid = getGrandidsession();
  if (gid) {
    await handleOrderSignature(gid);
  }
}

async function handleOrderSignature(gid) {
  const order = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("ORDER_TO_BE_PLACED"));
  if (order) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("ORDER_TO_BE_PLACED");
    order.grandIdSession = gid;
    const res = await placeOrder(order, order.placedByOrgId); // THIS IS THE SLOW API CALL
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Because I am running my React app in strict mode the component mounts twice, and because of this line:

> sessionStorage.removeItem("ORDER_TO_BE_PLACED");

The order item is not present in the second mount which then returns and start the execution of ApiCall_B :)

Comment: It should be `then(ApiCall_B)` otherwise you're calling `ApiCall_B` by using `()` instead of the `.then()` calling it for you

Comment: @NickParsons you're right. However, I found a second issue which I published as an comment regarding the sessionStorage.RemoveItem() and multiple mounts in strict mode.